# JQuery final countdown with multiple instances and time

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, final

I'm trying to use JQuery final countdown with multiple instances and time, however can't seem to get it working. Date `data-countdown` is formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

```
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
              var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
              console.log(finalDate)
              $this.countdown(finalDate,function(event) {
                  $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
                })
                .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
                  $(this).html('This offer has expired!')
                    .parent().addClass('disabled');

                });
            });
```

Anyone have any ideas or has achieved the same thing? Thanks

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: Is there no difference between `$this`, `this` and `$(this)`? at first sight here it looks like a mess

Comment: $this == this == $(this), I don't think thats the problem. TBH I think the problem is with the date format. The docs have an example with the following usage: $('#clock').countdown('2020/10/10 12:34:56'). This is exactly how the date I am passing to $this.countdown is formatted, but when I log the event it's specifying invalid date.